# how to detect if excel file open from one drive is readonly using office.js

Tags: office-js, office365-apps

I am developing an excel web app add-in for office365, my excel file is placed in one drive. When I open my excel file it shows in read-only mode. Is it possible using office.js or any javascript code to detect if a file is in read-only?

[image]

I tried url in the browser changes if you edit the excel so that can be used to detect if a file is in read-only mode or edit mode. right now you can see it as view.aspx page.

I also tried using `window.location`, but as this app stays in an iframe, it's difficult to get parents url location.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such API we can detect the Office model at present. You may consider to try to set the value to the selected cell to see whether it could work as a workaround. For example, it it is read-only mode, the set data action would failed.

Here is an example for your reference:

```
Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(asyncResult.value, function (asyncResult) {
                app.showNotification(asyncResult.status);
            })
        }
    })
```

And if you want the Office add-in to support this feature, you may submit the feedback [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: this doesn't work, from app it writes the value, but doesnt allow user to write it. any other thing you can suggest.

Comment: i can even add the worksheet from my app, but when i refresh the browser worksheet is not there

Comment: What's the scenario you were working? If it do need to detect detect the work mode, you may consider to submit the feedback.

Comment: As such if its in readonly mode its not usable, user can do all the actions can see the data what addin can bring but it wont be persist, so we wanted to show user a message to edit it, so that his work wont go waste..thanks,

Comment: We have similar scenario. The read-only state cannot be recognized from the add-in. The good part is Excel will tell the users they have changes they need to save when closing Excel. Hitting Save will actually open the Save as... dialogue. We educate our users for now. Yeah, bad thing but nothing you can do for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Document.mode](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.mode) property to determine if a file is Read Only. This property returns either `readOnly` or `readWrite`. It is supported across Word, Excel and PowerPoint on Desktop and Online.

Comment: that does not work, that property only give the mode for plugin not for excel file